# Spring Pageable: Nav Bar Pages by TotalPages

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I have a Spring application, and i get a response with as Pageable object and i have a content with the results and more information abourt the pages like that:

```
    data
:
content
:
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
first
:
true
last
:
false
number
:
0
numberOfElements
:
10
size
:
10
sort
:
[{…}]
totalElements
:
674
totalPages
:
68
```

And I want to make under my table a nav bar with the numbers of pages.

I tried on my angular module like that:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('PoepleController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.mc = '';
  $scope.poeples = [];
  $scope.page=0;
  $scope.pages=[];
  $scope.size=10;
  $scope.response={};

  $scope.SearchPoeple = function(){
      $http.get("http://localhost:8080/poeples?page="+ $scope.page+"&size="+$scope.size+"&mc="+$scope.mc)
      .then(function(data){
          $scope.poeples = data.data.content;
          $scope.response = data;
          console.log(data);
          $scope.pages = Array(data.data.totalPages)
      }, function(err){
          console.log(err);
      });
  }
  $scope.SearchPoeple();
});
```

And in my html page I tried to repeat on my pages array that i initialized with lenght of totalPages of my response.

```
</div>
    <div class="row">
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li><a href="#" aria-label="Previous"> <span
                        aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                </a></li>
                <li ng-repeat="pge in pages track by $index"><a href="#">{{ &index }}</a></li>

                <li><a href="#" aria-label="Next"> <span
                        aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                </a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

</div>
```

But It doesn't work.

Maybe It's not the good method. Somebody can Help Me !!

I think that it is a classical demand.

My second part is to limit in 5 items in the list. And to put previous and next button..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following, I will update if this isn't the total solution. $http requests are returned from the function they are called in because they return a promise.

```js
  $scope.SearchPoeple = function(){
      return $http
        .get("http://localhost:8080/poeples?page="+ $scope.page+"&size="+$scope.size+"&mc="+$scope.mc)
        .then(function(data){
            $scope.poeples = data.data.content;
            $scope.response = data;
            console.log(data);
            $scope.pages = new Array(data.data.totalPages);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
         });
  };
```

You have a syntax error on your Html Page. You have to correct $index and not &index!

Comment: @shmoolki did you get a response? if so what does it look like? if not what error are you seeing?

Comment: I have a response but i have this error too : app.js:16 Object
angular.min.js:124 Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%20character%20&p1=s%200-0%20%5B%26%5D&p2=%26index
    at angular.min.js:7
    at zc.throwError (angular.min.js:227)
    at zc.lex (angular.min.js:224)
    at r.ast (angular.min.js:231)
    at xc.parse (angular.min.js:266)
    at angular.min.js:134
    at h (angular.min.js:111)
    at oa (angular.min.js:82)
    at M (angular.min.js:66)
    at Va (angular.min.js:63)
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:124

Comment: I've updated the function, no need to call array on any part of the response, regardless of type.

Comment: @shmoolki updated, didn't mean to comment out. just need to remove the wrapper. and take it easy with the exclamation marks. they don't come off too nice.

Comment: excuse me, but if it's just a value, how can i make a repeat on this variable : <li ng-repeat="pge in pages track by $index"><a href="#">{{ &index }}</a></li>
    ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153883/discussion-between-alphapilgrim-and-shmoolki).